# In Ember.js, how to reveal Bootstrap modal after rendering into outlet

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, ember.js

In my Ember.js application I would like to open a Bootstrap modal from my `ApplicationRoute` when my `openModal` action is called.

I have this as my `ApplicationRoute`:

```
module.exports = Em.Route.extend({
    actions: {
        openModal: function(modalName) {
            this.render(modalName, {
                into: 'application',
                outlet: 'modal'
            });
            $('#active-modal').modal();
        }
    }
});
```

Now my issue is that `#active-modal` is not opened, probably because it doesn't exist in the DOM just after the `render` call.

How would I solve this?

Demo: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/cowoviwiwoyi/1/edit

Comment: You should read this: http://emberjs.com/guides/cookbook/user_interface_and_interaction/using_modal_dialogs/

Comment: @NicholasJohn16 Thanks, I did already though. Their example shows the modal as it's rendered. Whereas Bootstrap modals needs to be programmatically opened when the DOM node exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution in this article: http://mavilein.github.io/javascript/2013/08/01/Ember-JS-After-Render-Event/

This is the more elegant solution, it's not necessary to reopen `Ember.View` but then it works for all views when wanted.

Still the same `ApplicationRoute`:

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Em.Route.extend({
  actions: {
    showModal: function() {
      return this.render('modal', {
        into: 'application',
        outlet: 'modal'
      });
    }
    closeModal: function() {
      return this.disconnectOutlet({
        parentView: 'application',
        outlet: 'modal'
      });
    }
  }
});
```

But now we have overridden `Ember.View`'s `didInsertElement` to schedule a function call:

```
Em.View.reopen({
  didInsertElement: function() {
    this._super();
    Ember.run.scheduleOnce('afterRender', this, this.afterRenderEvent);
  }
});
```

Then I have defined ModalView explicitely and created a afterRenderEvent function on this, which finds the .modal DOM node and voila!

```
App.ModalView = Em.View.extend({
  afterRenderEvent: function() {
    this.$('.modal').modal();
  }
});
```

See it live: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/yifikuvebivu/1/edit

**Edit**

It's necessary to manually destroy the view, otherwise the modal will not appear again:

```
App.ModalView = Em.View.extend({
  var this = self;
  afterRenderEvent: function() {
    this.$('.modal')
        .on('hidden.bs.modal', function() {
          self.triggerAction({
            action: 'closeModal'
          });
        })
        .modal();
  }
});
```

**Edit 2**

There's an even better solution, which is necessary when creating modals with *components*. I have updated the code snippets above.

Answer (score -1):

do it inside `renderTemplate` Ember.Route hook method.

```
renderTemplate: function() {
    $('active-modal').modal();
}
```

Comment: In which route? Could you update the jsbin which what you propose?

Comment: Whichever route you open the modal. Rendertemplate hook gets called after the Dom has loaded, so jquery will pick it up.

Comment: As I expected, it breaks the rendering: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/yojiyaxeqacu/1/edit